# how to bring buttons in front of div in styled-components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

How can I bring Buttons in front of Component?

I already tried to put `position: relative` `z-index` properties into it.

```
import { Component } from './NavBar.style'
import Button from 'components/button/Button'

export default function NavBar() {
  return (
    <Component className='navbar'>
      <Button style='MenuBtn' type='button' />
      <Button style='MenuBtn' type='button' />
    </Component>
  )
}
```

```
import styled from 'styled-components'

export const Component = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: ${({ theme }) => theme.color.NavC};
  position: relative;

  & > button {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
  }
`
export default Component
```

Comment: `in front of Component` what does this mean?

Comment: Are you sure your `Button` component returns whatever it has to return? or maybe `NavBar` is not used hence you dont see anything being returned? You should check via chromes devtool kit to see if they are even being displayed. I created a simple app with the same component layout and css, with the use of `styled-components`, as you and it works fine for me: https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-grothendieck-r2qz5?file=/src/App.js . Guess you should provide us your `Button` code :|